# how to use cobertura code coverage tool with jar file

Tags: java, code-coverage, cobertura

I'm using cobertura to find out code coverage of my test suite, which tests a java based solution bundled through a jar file, [cobertura cmd line reference](http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/commandlinereference.html)

I have done the instrumentation part and obtained the instrument class files.
For the second step, I'm not sure whether I need to re-bundle the instrumented class files into a jar file since my test suite uses this jar file or can I simply set my CLASSPATH variable to include the instrumented class file while continue to use original jar file (which contains the uninstrumented class files).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include your instrumented files in the classpath BEFORE any other containers/Folders that may include the same compiled files.

In you case before the jar file with the instrumented files.

You don't need to rebundle.

Another possibility would be to instrument the jar file directly.

Comment: yes I though so and tried the same (including instrumented class files before any other jar/class files) but the data file .ser was not updated. Not sure what went wrong there. Maybe will try second option. Thanks.

Comment: if you deliberatley exclude the cobertura.jar fom the classpath you won't be able to run the tests because of classnotfound exceptions.
This could be a way to determine if java uses the instrumented classes.